# how to fix Cannot read property property 'size of' undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined. code-

```
var file_size = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0].size;
      console.log(file_size);
      if (file_size > 10000000) {
        alert("Ukuran file lebih besar dari 10MB");
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: the snippet you have added and the error you mentioned is not related at all , please update complete snippet and traceback for more clarity ..

Comment: You are not checking if there is a file uploaded or not, and if not the files array has no items and so the first index is undefined, and you are trying to access its size property so you receive that error message **"Cannot read property property 'size' of undefined"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
let files=$('input[type="file"]')[0].files;
if(files[0]?.size){
      var file_size = files[0].size;
      console.log(file_size);
      if (file_size > 10000000) {
        alert("Ukuran file lebih besar dari 10MB");
        return false;
      }
}
```